# Связи в Объектно Орентированном Программировании c#

Tags: c#, ооп

Всем привет:)
Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста, если Я передаю ссылку на объект в метод, какая это связь?

```
public void Method(MyClass my) // какая связь?
{
    //..
}
```

Если можно скиньте ссылки!

Композиция - всё ясно.

```
public class ElectricEngine { }

public class Car
{
    ElectricEngine engine;
    public Car()
    {
        engine = new ElectricEngine();
    }
}
```

Агрегация

```
public abstract class Engine
{ }

public class Car
{
    Engine engine;
    public Car(Engine eng)
    {
        engine = eng;
    }
}
```

Ассоциация

```
class Team
{

}
class Player
{
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Наследование и реализация - тоже не вызывают проблем)

Comment: а что происходит внутри этого метода?

Comment: работаем с ссылкой, к примеру:public void Method(MyClass my) 
{
    my.Mymethod();
}

Comment: на самом деле подходит под ассоциацию

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это зависимость.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, я не встречал четкого определения для связи "Зависимость", но во многх источниках под ней подразумевают два случая.

**Параметер в методе**

```
public void Method(MyClass my)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Создание локальной переменной**

```
public void Method()
{
    MyClass my = new MyClass();
    // ...
}
```

Если брать UML, то в нем определены еще конкретные зависимости: call, create, use и т.п.